# Uncompression Error...System Halted KaOS Live Usb

Tags: linux

I've live usb of KaOS and it doesn't booting.
Getting error...

> Uncompression Error...System Halted

I've checked RAM if it is cause of error but both RAMs are inserted and production system working fine.

`SHA256SUM` is different than downloaded file.
Would this can be cause of this kind of error?
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if hash is different this is indicator your download process somehow corrupt the original image. Download it again and be sure the hash match

Comment: Ok I'll try again downloading but does power failure can be cause of corruption ?

Comment: @SwapnilNagtilak, it can be